# Excel macro using if else,while loop

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I am trying to obtain the format as shown through a macro. Basically, the idea is if i have a huge number of data and if the material type is B, then the macro will create a blank row below it as long as the "balance" tab is not zero for it. Lastly, the balance will multiply the price/pax to obtain the total price.

I was thinking using if else, while loops would be possible but i am not sure how to go about it. 
The algo i was thinking..

```
         If Material type= B;
while Balance /= 0;
*create another empty role*;
Balance= Qty- Qty used;(a summation of all QTY used)
Tot.Price=Balance*Price/pax;
else,
ends
```

Is a macro able to reference to the header and update? Any advice on how I should go about it or changes?

Thanks Matt. I would like for it to be a "reactive" macro,ie to say everytime i enter a new value to the QTY used col, the macro would run. Is it possible? The material type B would probably occur a number of times, can the macro work for all B but doesnt affect each other?

After i run the macro,

[image]

Can the 60 take reference from the old balance value, subtract and return a new balance value? Which means 410 will replace 470. The extra row should be below 60. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track with your pseudo-code. The way I generally go about this sort of thing is to identify the last row of the data set and loop backwards (since you are inserting rows along the way) until you reach the top. So, something like this

```
finalRow = cells(65000,1).end(xlup).row
for i = finalRow to 2 step -1
  cells(i,7) = cells(i,5) - cells(i,6)
  cells(i,9) = cells(i,7) * cells(i,8)
  if cells(i,10) = "B" and cells(i,7) <> 0 then
    cells(i+1,1).entirerow.insert
  end if
next i
```

Comment: You could put the code in a worksheet_change module, I believe. Have you looked into that?

Comment: I should have said `Worksheet_SelectionChange(...)`

Comment: umm, no, but just did a browse through. Seems kinda tough.Is it to switch between 2 or more worksheets?

Comment: No, if you put the macro in a `Worksheet_SelectionChange(...)` module, then the macro will run every time you make a selection change. You can set it so it runs every time you enter a new number in the `QTY used` column.

Comment: Or using `Worksheet_Change(...)` may be even better.